# How to match element of one list with exactly one other element in another list in python?

Tags: python

I have two lists:
a=[1,2]
b=[1,2,1,1,1,2,2]
How do i match an element of list a with exactly the same element in list b only once.
I tried the code:

```
for unit in a:
    for nit in b:
        if unit==nit:
            print(unit,nit)
```

But it matches element in list a with all the similar matches with elements in list b. I need only a single match and not multiple matches.

So i tried removing the element to prevent further matches, as in the code:

I tried the code:

```
for unit in a:
    for nit in b:
        if unit==nit:
            print(unit,nit)
            a.remove(unit)
```

But it returns error.

Comment: What do you mean? What is the result you're trying to get?

Comment: `set(a).intersection(b)`?

Comment: Trivial answer: `break`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is what you want
But here is how I would do it

```
a=[1,2]
b=[1,2,1,1,1,2,2]
for unit in a:
    if unit in b:
        print (unit,unit)
```

I have printed unit twice to match the desired output.It works because it is the same element in b and we are ensuring that with our if condition

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
In [3]:  a=[1,2]

In [4]: b=[1,2,1,1,1,2,2]

In [5]: a_set = set(a)

In [6]: b_set = set(b)

In [7]: a_set.intersection(b_set)
Out[7]: {1, 2}
```

Comment: Or: `set(a) & set(b)` it will return `{1, 2}`